# Create CSS Skew to touch left right corners

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have created a sample of this which can be seen below

```css
.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
.box1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>

<div class="box2"></div>
```

This works fine when the screen is smaller but if you check on bigger screen, red skew shape goes out of the blue box from left side.

As the transform-origin is given to point bottom-right corner of the blue box.
Is there a way so that on any solution, this skew shape stays in the middle of the blue and green boxes? So it should hide the merging line of these 2 boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.box1 {
  height: 300px;
  background:lightblue;
  position:relative;
}
.box1:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-100px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,lightblue 30%,red 31%,red 70%,lightgreen 71%);
  transform:skewY(-6deg);
}
.box2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is another idea with background image:

```css
.box1 {
  height: 300px;
  background:url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/);
  position:relative;
}
.box1:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,red 50.5%);
}
.box2 {
  height: 300px;
  background:url(https://lorempixel.com/800/1000/);
  position:relative;
}
.box2:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,red 50.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: Actually I have different content in blue box and green boxes. So this idea will not work. They are 2 separate divs and this shape needs to act like a divider between these 2 divs. Infact there are event more divs on same page that needs this kind of separation.

Comment: Good idea but what if the box1 has background image?

Comment: Also the gradients don't look very sharp

Comment: @aslamdoctor the intial skew also is not very sharp :) and ok am gonna do it wilth background image ;)

Comment: @aslamdoctor check again ;)

Comment: @aslamdoctor play with the % value of colors .. make them close to remove the blur ... check update again

Comment: Yeah, nice work. I am going to play with this more. You get the right answer :)